# Fatal error: Class 'F0FTable' not found in Joomla after upgrading to 3.9 build

Tags: joomla

Fatal error: Class 'F0FTable' not found in Joomla after upgrading to 3.9 build. I can't see the folder F0F in the libraries folder

Comment: In the future, when you have Joomla questions, please post at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the j2store plugin that was not properly installed. I removed it manually and solved the issue.

Thanks